# Postgresql : создание результирующей колонки

Tags: sql, postgresql

подскажите.

Имеется таблица: product_id(int), green(boolean), red(boolean)

Нужно **создать** таблицу: product_id(int), green_or_red(boolean),

в которой в столбце green_or_red будет результат сравнение (green or red)

Пример: product_id(10), green(True), red(False) --> product_id(10), green_or_red(True)

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

С помощью триггера. При инсерте в таблицу product_id(int), green(boolean), red(boolean) еще и инсертить product_id(int), green(boolean), red(boolean)

Comment: не совсем то, что нужно